# Can Lebesgue Dominated Convergence always be used?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, derivatives, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Suppose I want to find the derivative 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x,y) dy.$$
I want to know under what condition it would be equal to 
$$\int \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y) dy.$$
Of course, if I can find a suitable dominating function $H$, then I can use LDCT.  In other words, we know that $$\text{Existence of a dominating function } H \implies \left(\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x,y) dy=\int \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y) dy\right).$$  But is this actually an if and only if?  In other words, does interchangeability of the derivative and integral necessarily imply the existence of a dominating function $H$ which I can use to apply LDCT, i.e., $$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x,y) dy=\int \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y) dy\right) \implies \text{Existence of a dominating function } H.$$

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure your question is even well-defined (which may explain the downvote). What is the exact statement you want to (dis)prove?

Comment: @ClementC Is the question now better formed?  I agree that I was in a rush and made a mess of it.

Comment: I would appreciate if those downvoting or voting to close would give reasons here in the comments so I can address your concerns.  That way I know if it is a stupid question or a stupidly written question.  I can obsvioulsy fix the latter and apologize for the messiness of my original question.  I was trying to do several things at once.

Comment: Also, if the downvotes were due to a poorly worded question, I would appreciate if people could upvote to get me back to zero since I fixed the question.

Comment: Sadly, hoping that downvoters would explain their decision is tantamount to asking for a pony (to say the least, based on premedical validation). I am still not really understanding your question, so will myself let to other people the choice of judging its relevance.

Comment: @ClementC. Can you read the question one more time and see if you understand it now?  I really appreciate the input you have provided.

Comment: I reckon it's much easier/possible to interpret now (incidentally, for what it's worth you may want to throw some more keywords about $H$, e.g. "integrable"). I don't have an answer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this more well-defined, let's say $f$ is a function on $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ which is differentiable with respect to $x$ at $x=0$ for all $y$, 
and $f(x, \cdot) \in L^1[-1,1]$ for all $x$, and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0, \cdot) \in L^1[-1,1]$.  Thus it makes sense to ask
whether 
$$ \left.\dfrac{d}{d x} \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y)\; dy\right|_{x=0} = \int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)\; dy \tag{1}$$
To use Dominated Convergence, you would want some $\epsilon > 0$ and $g \in L^1$ such that
$$ \left| \dfrac{f(x,y) - f(0,y)}{x}\right| \le g(y)\ \text{for}\ 0 < |x|<\epsilon \tag{2}$$

To find examples where (1) is true but not (2), you might rely on symmetry to make (1) work.  For example, this will be true if $f(x,y)$ is an odd function of $y$ for every $x$.  So e.g. try

$$ f(x,y) = \cases{\dfrac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^4} & $y \ne 0$\cr
                      0  & $y = 0$\cr}$$
noting that $f(y,y)/y = 1/(2y^2)$ for $y \ne 0$, so that (2) fails, but both sides of (1) are $0$, indeed $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y)\; dy = \int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\; dy = 0\ \text{for all}\ x$$